# When UITableView is editing and can be moved , then how to change the background color of the move button which is in right side of the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to change gray color to the background color of the cell,but when the UITableView is editing and can be moved, then there is a move button in right side of the cell, but the background color of the button is white. How can i change the background color of the move button to gray ?

Here is the image:
[There is white color in right side of the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te8hI.jpg)

Comment: How are you setting up background color currently ?
Make sure you set background color on "contentView" not cell itself

Comment: i had set background color on "contentView" . `self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];`

Comment: Try to set cell.backgroundColor as well

Comment: That's right , both i need to set background color on `contentView` and cell itself .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to customize your tableviewcell best practice is use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` there is two ways to change the background color of a cell

1. `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`,content view is a view which holds all the objects added to it,changing its background colour will not affect the BG of **Accessory's or editing accessory's**.
2. `cell.backgroundColor` but this one changes the entire background of the cell including all accessories.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
   }
   ```

By changing background colour of cell we can change **EditingAcc** BG.

[image]